Error: "Unable to find database home folder" during installation SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP Developer Edition 7.52 SP04
I'm attempting to install the SAP NetWeaver AS ABAP Developer Edition 7.52 SP04 following the tutorial at: https://abapacademy.com/blog/how-to-install-free-sap-system/. However, I encountered an error "Assertion failed: Unable to find database home folder." for which I haven't found any solutions.
I'm using VirtualBox and openSUSE.
Logs:

ERROR      2024-04-18 19:07:50.256 (root/sapinst) (startInstallation) [CInstallerCallBackImpl.cpp:259] id=ind-rel.ind-os.ind-db.assertionFailed errno=CJS-00030 CInstallerCallBackImpl::abortInstallation()
Assertion failed: Unable to find database home folder.
ERROR      2024-04-18 19:07:50.257 (root/sapinst) (startInstallation) [iaxxbjsmod.cpp:83] id=modlib.jslib.caughtException errno=MUT-03025
Caught ESAPinstException in module call: Assertion failed: Unable to find database home folder..
ERROR      2024-04-18 19:07:50.404 (root/sapinst) (startInstallation) [CSiStepExecute.cpp:1104] id=controller.stepExecuted errno=FCO-00011 CSiStepExecute::execute()
The step syb_dialog_check_sw_folder with step key |offlineadjustment_dialogs|ind|ind|ind|ind|0|0|offlineadjustment_db_post|ind|ind|ind|ind|db_post|0|syb_rename_db_post_dia|ind|ind|ind|ind|syb|0|NW_SYB_DB_REN|ind|ind|ind|ind|syb2|0|syb_dialog_check_sw_folder was executed with status ERROR (Last error reported by the step: Assertion failed: Unable to find database home folder).

Does anyone have any ideas?

I don't know this tutorial. Use the SAP official guide instead: AS ABAP 7.52 SP04, Developer Edition: Concise Installation Guide.

Hi Sandra,
Thank you for response.
The official guide is almost identical. However, I managed to solve the problem. I had to skip a step because when I restarted the installation from the beginning, it progressed further. But now I'm encountering a new issue:
"=>sapparam(1c): No Profile used.
=>sapparam: SAPSYSTEMNAME neither in Profile nor in Commandline"

If you can, please post an answer, but be more detailed. A new issue, a new question. The installation is very sensitive, you must follow the guide perfectly, otherwise it ends with issues. There could be errors in the future even if it appears to be fine at first glance.

I've decided to try installing it via Docker, and it worked. So the problem is no longer relevant. Thank you very much for your help.

For information, see: I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?.
